# Play Scala JSON Reads converter: mapping nested properties

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-json

I have the following case class:

```
case class User(name: String, age: String)
```

I am trying to implement a JSON `Reads` converter for it, so I can do the following:

```
val user = userJson.validate[User]
```

… but the incoming JSON has slightly different structure:

```
{ "age": "12", "details": { "name": "Bob" } }
```

How can I implement my JSON `Reads` converter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using combinators to parse sub-paths.

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

case class User(name: String, age: String)

val js = Json.parse("""
    { "age": "12", "details": { "name": "Bob" } }
""")

implicit val reads: Reads[User] = (
    (__ \ "details" \ "name").read[String] and
    (__ \ "age").read[String]
)(User.apply _)    

scala> js.validate[User]
res2: play.api.libs.json.JsResult[User] = JsSuccess(User(Bob,12),)
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure if it would be better to have a class for validating the user JSON, and a separate class with the data structured to suit my preferences. Is the above use case abusing JSON Reads for something they are not designed for?